# How to implement message passing for a single message?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have implemented a job/task system. You can create a `function<void, void>` and place it on a thread local queue, before that I wrap the function in a Fiber.

Now that works perfectly fine at the moment but it would be quite useless if I can not return values.`function<T, void>`

That means I would need a way to do message passing. I implemented it this way:

I have a `Cell<T>` which can store a variable and has an atomic counter. I take a `function<T, void>`, wrap in in a closure. Once the function has been executed it will write into the `cell` and decrement the counter. Now when I create the `closure` I have to pointer to a cell, one is inside the closure and one is outside.

The closure is of type `function<void, void>` and I also wrap it in a fiber and put it in a thread local queue.

Now outside of the task system I can check that cell if the counter has decremented to 0. If it has I know the `task` must have finished, otherwise I have to wait. I only wait in the main thread outside of the task system. Inside the task system I can just reschedule.

I have not done any multihreaded programming before and this was the only way that I could imagine to implement "message passing".

I am pretty sure that something like my `Cell` has already been invented, but I am not sure what the general name for it is.

Is this a common way to implement message passing? By that I mean "Wrapping a `cell` inside a closure and wait for completion".

What is the correct name of my `Cell` and are there any implementations of it available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to pass one message, and it's called "future". A "future" is an object that will hold a value in (near) future (hence the name), and you can poll it (or wait) in order to get the value. In C++11, it exists under the form of [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). The emitter side of a future is a [`promise`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise).

For your case:

1. someone gives a `std::function<T()>` to be scheduled for execution
2. you wrap this function in a fiber. While doing this, you should actually wrap it in a `std::function<void()>` first:

   ```
   std::promise<T> promise;
   std::future<T> future = promise.get_future();
   std::function<void()> wrapped = [f, p = std::move(promise)]()
   {
       p.set_value(f());
   };
   // do stuff with 'wrapped'
   return future;
   ```
3. With the returned future you can either wait for a value (blocking call) or poll it to know when the value is done.

Bonus: you can also create a `std::future<void>`, in which case you can still call `get()` or still poll it; it will act a signal for the completion of the function.